# combine jQuery filters for :visible and :enabled

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-filter

I need to select form elements and limit the list to elements that are both visible and enabled.

The following works:

```
myInputs.filter(':visible').filter(':enabled');
```

This does not (it does not remove disabled elements):

```
myInputs.filter(':visible, :enabled');
```

Is there a better way to combine these two filters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `comma` from that selector to make your concept working.

Try,

```
myInputs.filter(':visible:enabled');
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks for the fast response. 13 minutes from now SO will allow me to accept your answer. :)